# Adding Actions to ListView Items

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having some issues trying to figure out how to add actions to all of my items in a listview. What I mean is that I want to do something when an item is pressed. Right now, I press an item and there is no action. I want it to do something and thats where I need help.

Here is the code I use in my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViedoStream viedoStream_data[] = new ViedoStream[]
    {
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image0, "Mission TV"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image1, "HCBN Philippines"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image2, "Global Family Network"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image3, "2CBN"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image4, "Red ADvenir"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image5, "Alfa Television"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image6, "Light Channel Hungary"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image7, "Light Channel Rumania"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image8, "Light Channel Germany"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image9, "Terceiro Anjo"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image10, "HCBN Indonesia"),
        new ViedoStream(R.drawable.image11, "TV Famille")
    };

    ViedoStreamAdapter adapter = new ViedoStreamAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, viedoStream_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

What an item is pressed, I want to play a video stream from an http stream but I have an idea of how to perform this type of action. I just need to know how to make it do something.

Can someone help me on doing this? I am new to Android platform by the way.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of actions?

Comment: EDIT* Read again my post. Sorry... I was not clear.

Comment: To perform action, when item is pressed you should set listener. Here is link to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
 listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TV Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           //  Place code here with the action

        }
   });
```

For those of you who are getting errors, remember to add this import: import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Thank you :)